# On the typing tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typing) tag on Stack Overflow has two different meanings:

- The process of assigning types to program fragments (that's what the tag means on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/typing)).
- The process of pressing keys on a keyboard (that's what the tag means on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags/typing)).

The current tag wiki states

> For questions related to data types. Do not use this tag for questions related to the physical act of typing on a keyboard, as such questions are almost always off-topic.

but there are nonetheless on-topic questions where the keyboard meaning is valid and the tag would be useful for searching, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920590/javascript-typewriter-effect-using-array) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935125/word-macro-for-movie-typing).

There is a [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types) tag, which has a different meaning from [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typing): [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typing) is about the process of assigning the types, [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types) is about the types themselves and the language's type system. I'm not sure if the distinction is really made by most taggers on SO.

Should there be a tag for typing as in types and one for typing as in keyboards? Under what names?

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that a question is about simulation of typing (the process of writing or inputting text by pressing keys on a typewriter, keyboard, cell phone, or a calculator) doesn't seem so relevant to require a tag.

I am thinking of questions where the topic is:

- Showing a message letter after letter, as if it were typed in real time from a user
- Showing a specific text independently from what the user is typing, but showing a new character every time a user presses a key
- Reproducing a sound every time a user presses a key, as if s/he were typing from a typewriter